# Batch Dos Loop write line every Thd numeric value

Tags: loops, batch-file, count, line, dos

I need to write a container   every 5 lines...
Example:

```
div container

   div 1,2,3,4,5

/div container
```

My batch

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "C:\img\*.jpg" ') DO (
  SET /a seq=1000000000+%%~na
  ECHO !seq!) 
)>"%temp%\tempfile"
FOR /f %%a IN ('sort "%temp%\tempfile"') DO (
 SET /a seq=%%a-1000000000

:: break point block <div container> open

  ECHO ^<div^>^<a href='images/%imgfolder%/full/!seq!.jpg'^>^</a^>^</div^> >>%page%.html 

:: break point block </div container> closed

)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should explain your problem in plain words. If your Batch file does not solve your problem, then it have not sense to post it instead of a description of your problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of your problem is not clear enough, so I have to guess several points. The Batch file below assume the following requirements:

- In `C:\img` folder there are several *.jpg files with names with numbers, like `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, etc.
- The solution should generate a div container with 5 .jpg files each in the right order.

This is my solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get existent *.jpg files and sort they in the right order
for %%a in (C:\img\*.jpg) do (
   set /A seq=1000000000+%%~Na
   set file[!seq!]=%%a
)

rem Generate div containers with groups of 5 files each
set i=0
(for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set file[') do (
   set /A i+=1, iMOD5=i %% 5

   if !iMOD5! equ 1 (
      rem break point block <div container> open
      ECHO ^<div^>
   )

   rem Output this file in the group of 5
   echo ^<a href='images/%imgfolder%/full/%%~NXa'^>^</a^>

   if !iMOD5! equ 0 (
      rem break point block </div container> closed
      echo ^</div^>
   )

)) > %page%.html

rem Close the last div container, if any
if %iMOD5% neq 0 (
   echo ^</div^>>> %page%.html
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every 0th and 5th iterence, it will call the `write_container` function, you can adjust the numbers to your liking (like 1, and 6).
try this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "C:\img\*.jpg" ') DO (
    SET /a seq=1000000000+%%~na
    ECHO !seq!) 
)>"%temp%\tempfile"
set counter=0
FOR /f %%a IN ('sort "%temp%\tempfile"') DO (
    SET /a seq=%%a-1000000000
    SET /a counter+=1

    if "!counter:~-1!"=="0" call :write_container
    if "!counter:~-1!"=="5" call :write_container

    :: break point block <div container> open

    ECHO ^<div^>^<a href='images/%imgfolder%/full/!seq!.jpg'^>^</a^>^</div^> >>%page%.html 

    :: break point block </div container> closed

)  

goto skip_write_container
:write_container
:: Enter the container code here


goto :eof
:skip_write_container
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect job ... 
I just set the startup counter ...
you wrote ** counter set = 0 ** ...
I have changed in set = -1 ** counter ** ... to start counting from 1.jpg to N..
Thank you again.

Comment: @gerry_76  There is a way of thanking people - read the help `tour` on accepting answers.